# How can I use WPF menus and dialog boxes in F#?

Tags: wpf, menu, f#, dialog

I've been trying to find an example of using XAML and F# - without C# - to set up traditional menus and dialog boxes. Everything I can find online either uses C# or it is old, before the most recent versions of F# and .NET. Can anyone suggest an example I can look at?  Thanks.

Comment: http://fsprojects.github.io/FsXaml/

Comment: you will need FsXAML and either FSharp.ViewModule or [Gjallarhorn](https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn/tree/master/samples) to do  binding. The latter has a few samples.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for responding.  I'll look where you suggest and try to figure it out.  If anyone else has any other ideas, please add them to this list.

Comment: As this is quite open ended, you should probably come by the [F# chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f) or even better [F# Slack](http://foundation.fsharp.org/join).

Comment: I would love to use the chatroom, but I'm new here and I only have 19 rep points and I need 20 to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to learn WPF, you come across many C# examples based on "good old" code behind rather than MVVM or MVC. The following explains how to quickly create an F# WPF code behind application. Using this, it becomes easier to experiment with all those examples.

Create an F# console application.

Change the **Output type** of the application to *Windows Application*.

Add **FsXaml** from NuGet.

Add these four source files, and arrange them in this order.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="First Demo" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Canvas>
        <Button Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="28" Width="72"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.fs

```
namespace FirstDemo

type MainWindowXaml = FsXaml.XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

type MainWindow() =
    inherit MainWindowXaml()

    let whenLoaded _ =
        ()

    let whenClosing _ =
        ()

    let whenClosed _ =
        ()

    let btnTestClick _ =
        this.Title <- "Yup, it works!"
        ()

    do
        this.Loaded.Add whenLoaded
        this.Closing.Add whenClosing
        this.Closed.Add whenClosed
        this.btnTest.Click.Add btnTestClick
```

App.xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.fs

```
namespace FirstDemo

open System
open System.Windows

type App = FsXaml.XAML<"App.xaml">

module Main =

    [<STAThread; EntryPoint>]
    let main _ =
        let app = App()
        let mainWindow = new MainWindow()
        app.Run(mainWindow) // Returns application's exit code.
```

Delete the *Program.fs* file.

Change the **Build Action** to *Resource* for the two xaml files.

Add a reference to the .NET assembly **UIAutomationTypes**.

Compile and run.

You can't use the designer to add event handlers. Simply add them manually in the code behind.

StackOverflow is possibly not the best place to post complete demos like this one, especially if this spins off more questions along the same line. If there is another better place, e.g. a public repo for this kind of thing, please let me know.

Comment: Bent, thank you, thank you, thank you!  It's my birthday today and your reply is the best present I got.  Your answer was simple, step-by-step, and it actually worked.  Now I have to learn from it and see if I can apply it to menus and dialog boxes in WPF.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. If you need help with controls, how to add window icons, an application icon, and possibly other stuff, then just ask again. Most stuff is like C#, but the bits that are specific to F# can be really hard to google.

Comment: Oh, and - happy birthday, Bob!

Comment: I adde more material here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/f%23/9008/f-wpf-code-behind-application-with-fsxaml

Comment: And I added my solution in a Spirograph application here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/f%23/9145/using-f-wpf-fsxaml-a-menu-and-a-dialog-box#t=201702200527195231483