# F# FsXaml: Which events are supported for which controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#, fsxaml

`<Button Click="MyClickMethod" />` works fine; the XAML type provider  exposes `MyClickMethod` as a virtual method in the code-behind.

On the other hand, `override this.MyDoubleClickMethod (_, _)` gets the pretty red underlining for `<ListBox MouseDoubleClick="MyDoubleClickMethod" />`, and of course my program fails to compile.

If `ListBox` events aren't supported, then it sure would have been nice to know this before I got three days into coding my application.  Is FsXaml well documented anywhere (and I don't mean the source code)?  What's the generally accepted work-around for my problem?

**EDIT :** Here are my code files (minus `AssemblyInfo.fs` and `App.*` boilerplate), in Solution Explorer order:

**MainViewModel.fs:**

```
namespace MyWpf.ViewModels

open ViewModule
open ViewModule.FSharp

type MainViewModel () as self = 
    inherit ViewModelBase ()

    let myItems = self.Factory.Backing (<@ self.MyItems @>, Array.empty)

    do
        self.MyItems <- [| "cheeseburger"; "French fries"; "chocolate shake" |]

    member this.MyItems
        with get () = lock myItems (fun () -> myItems.Value)
        and private set value = lock myItems (fun () -> myItems.Value <- value)
```

**MainView.xaml.fs:**

```
namespace MyWpf.Views

open System.Windows

type MainViewBase = FsXaml.XAML<"MainView.xaml">
type MainView () =
    inherit MainViewBase ()

    override this.MyDoubleClickMethod (_, _) = MessageBox.Show "click!" |> ignore
```

**MainView.xaml:**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyWpf.ViewModels;assembly=MyWpf">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox
            Name="MyList"
            Width="300"
            Height="224"
            Margin="10,4,10,4"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
            MouseDoubleClick="MyDoubleClickMethod" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.fs:**

```
namespace MyWpf.Windows

type MainWindow = FsXaml.XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyWpf.Views;assembly=MyWpf"
    Width="320"
    Height="240"
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <views:MainView />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917667/how-can-i-use-wpf-menus-and-dialog-boxes-in-f

Comment: I stopped using FsXaml around 1.5 year ago when I realized we can't expect much further development and maintenance of it. Better newer options exists today for XAML + F#. Gjallarhorn is a successor to FsXaml in the sense that Reed Copsey started both. Another alternative is Elmish.WPF. Then there's the possibility to use MVVM, and put your XAML files in a C# project, and still have practically all your code in F#. If you want to discuss any of this, I suggest you go to F# Slack, since SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: It just works to me. Can you please provide MCVE? Although I personally find old style preferable: `do self.myListBox.MouseDoubleClick.Add(fun _ -> 
        // do something
        ()
        )`

Comment: Bent T., I'm not sure what your link is meant to reveal.  There's no code pertaining to the ListBox control, there.

Foggy F., I've added the source code, which fails to compile.   The compiler complains about the MyDoubleClickMethod override in MainView.xaml.fs.